# Bootstraped table - smaller font size

Tags: html, css

I'm using bootstrap table in my html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
.table-condensed {
width: 90% !important;
}
```

And I'd like to make font size in table much smaller. How can I adjust current code to have desired output. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/) for your code?

Comment: add `font-size:9px !important` in your `.table-condensed` css selector

Answer (score 51):

sir. I would try something like this:

```css
.table-condensed{
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@example.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I got this fiddle your you: https://jsfiddle.net/mqhd0js6/ .
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! As " .table-condensed {
    font-size: 12px !important;
} " it works perfectly

Answer (score 18):

in bootstrap 4 :

```
<table class="table w-auto small">
```

or

```
<table class="table w-auto text-xsmall">
```

I use it and work.

Answer (score 12):

Another option:

```
<table class="table table-sm">
</table>
```

And in the case you will use the previous solution, I would suggest to use 
REM units instead of pixels to keep the font size consistent.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add a `font-size: 8px;` to your CSS selector.

Replace 8 by any number you wish to change your font-size to.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {  
    .table-responsive {
        font-size:10px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's always best to add an explanation as to what your code does and why it solves the stated problem. Code only answers may lead to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: this is being activated when the device has that resolution